# Can I make a graph for iterative function in MS Excel or Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

Let's say I have a formula:

```
k = 0.2
a = pow(a, k)
```

I'd like to see how the curve changes on each iteration with a different `k` value. The formula can be anything. The only thing is - I need the previous value to calculate next. And let's say I need 1000 iterations.

*PS: I'm not sure if I use the correct words for it.*

Comment: What is the initial value of a?

Comment: Also what is your graph axes? Are you plotting a vs. i (series are different k's) where i is 0..1000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my example I literally took the function as a^k and assumed an initial value of a = 1.1. You want a row of data for each iteration.

[image]

Formula view:
[image]

Comment: Oh, this is awesome! Thank you very much! :3